# Why is the wrong ctor being called?

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit

I have code that works as expected:

```
EscapedString es("Abc&def");
EscapedString es2("");
es2 = es;     // es2 == Abc%26def
```

And code that doesn't work as expected:

```
EscapedString es("Abc&def");
EscapedString es2 = es;    // es == Abc%2526def
```

In the second case, the CTOR2 is called instead of CTOR3 even though `es` is an EscapedString.

```
EscapedString es(EscapedString("Abc?def"));
```

Does the right thing, but I can't seem to set a breakpoint on CTOR3 so I'm not sure it is working correctly, or the code has been optimized away or it is accidentally working.

The class is below:

```
class EscapedString : public std::string {
public:
    EscapedString(const char *szUnEscaped) {  // CTOR1
        *this = szUnEscaped;
    }

    EscapedString(const std::string &strUnEscaped) {   // CTOR2
        *this = strUnEscaped;
    }

    explicit EscapedString(const EscapedString &strEscaped) {   // CTOR3
        *this = strEscaped;  // Can't set breakpoint here
    }

    EscapedString &operator=(const std::string &strUnEscaped) {
        char *szEscaped = curl_easy_escape(NULL, strUnEscaped.c_str(), strUnEscaped.length());
        this->assign(szEscaped);
        curl_free(szEscaped);
        return *this;
    }
    EscapedString &operator=(const char *szUnEscaped) {
        char *szEscaped = curl_easy_escape(NULL, szUnEscaped, strlen(szUnEscaped));
        this->assign(szEscaped);
        curl_free(szEscaped);
        return *this;
    }
    EscapedString &operator=(const EscapedString &strEscaped) {
        // Don't re-escape the escaped value
        this->assign(static_cast<const std::string &>(strEscaped));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: i think it has to do with your operator overloading.

Comment: Probably because you made your copy constructor explicit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally, `EscapedString es2 = es;` will call the copy constructor, however you explicitly told it not to by making the copy constructor `explicit`:

```
explicit EscapedString(const EscapedString &strEscaped)
```

A constructor marked `explicit` can never be called by means of automatic type conversions.  It can only be called, well... explicitly, which you have done here:

```
EscapedString es(EscapedString("Abc?def"));
```

Here's what happens when the compiler encounters `EscapedString es2 = es;`.

First the compiler sees if it can use the copy constructor and finds that it can't, because it was marked `explicit`.  So it looks for another constructor to call.  Since `EscapedString` is derived from `std::string`, the compiler is able to cast `es` as a `const std::string&` and call:

```
EscapedString &operator=(const std::string &strUnEscaped)
```